# Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute rx="-3" in Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highstock to create a column chart with scroll bar (includes lazy loading feature also)

I'm seeing this error in my console.

```
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute rx="-3" in Highstock
```

I'm not getting when and what is the cause for this error.
Did any one of you come across the same or similar error while Using highcharts/highstock.

Please help me with to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Can you reproduce your example as live demo ?